# What information is described by an Enterprise Architecture Diagram?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagram

I'm tasked with building a set of Architectural Diagrams to share with a third party.  Most have been pretty familiar, but the request for an Enterprise Architectural Diagram has me a bit stuck.  I'm not exactly sure what information this particular diagram is supposed to convey to the reader.

Comment: Ask whoever asked you to make one for clarification?

Comment: I'm concurrently doing just that.  But I'm trying to get this done ASAP, so I am posting this here for insights as well.

Comment: Also, the information on this topic around the internet sucks. So maybe having some good answers here will be useful for the next guy that comes along.

Comment: scope=Enterprise, describes=Architecture, form=Diagram, things they'll probably want to read from it is `deployment diagram`, inter system `communication diagram`, high level overview of the business processes (`BPMN`). Find out who will be the readers and what they want to get clarified. (If you don't have a slightest idea what should be the deliverable and why then you're probably not the one who should be assigned that task)

Comment: @xmojmr I think you hit it on the head.  I'm probably not the guy, but I think there may not be anyone else.  I'm the only Architect on staff, but I work more in the Application and Solution levels.  Any business Architecture is done informally and passed down to me only through goals and directives.  Communicating the Enterprise picture just isn't something I have had to do before.

Comment: if there is no one else then finding out what the readers want would be good 1st step. If readers also don't know what they want, then give them "anything" that you think will be useful for them. I also don't know what this 3-word acronym is supposed to mean. But as always I would start with examples and as always I would start with examples from http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html and from those available from http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/index.html and Google: "bpmn examples" (especially images). Good luck, it is a challenge

Answer (score 1):

Neither UML nor SysML defines an Enterprise Architecture Diagram. It might be that there is a clear definition of this diagram type in some other modelling language or framework, but if so I am not aware of it.

Modelling an actual enterprise architecture can be done using TOGAF or some other framework, but that's a pretty massive task (which easily results in dozens or hundreds of diagrams) and certainly not something you either throw in at the last minute, or ask for on a whim.

If they did specify one rather than a set of such diagrams, my guess would be that they're asking for a high-level overview in a relaxed format which mixes different views to provide a kind of "executive summary" diagram. Check out [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_context_diagram), especially what the second example refers to as an "architecture interconnect diagram," that might be what they're after.

Comment: or this one http://www.zive.cz/Getfile.aspx?id_file=683999257 - I have seen that sort of pictures already before also on Microsoft's and Google's pages but the pictures usually don't follow any known syntax or rules, they seem just like adhoc pictures invented just to visualize something in a small space. "executive summary" fits as description

Comment: or http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf pages 6 and 7, pictures "OpenGL Compute Programming Model and Compute Memory Hierarchy", "OpenGL Texture Views and Texture Object State", "OpenGL Pipeline" (just rename buffers to "stakeholders"?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the term "Enterprise Architectural Diagram" has a well-defined meaning, while "Enterprise Architecture" refers to the attempt of holistically describing an enterprise, including its IT and application systems, as a ***socio-technical system***. Making such a complete description of an enterprise (in the form of a bunch of diagrammatic and textual models and accompanying documents) is certainly an important, but possibly too ambitious, goal.

There are a number of proposals how to make an "Enterprise Architecture". The most prominent historical proposal is the [Zachman Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachman_Framework). A more recent proposal is [ArchiMate](http://www.opengroup.org/standards/ea), which is a standard of the *Open Group*. In all these proposals, a number of ***stakeholders*** and their ***viewpoints*** have to be identified such that a set of viewpoint-specific models at different levels of abstraction help to describe all relevant aspects of the enterprise, including all sorts of business management and IT issues. Modeling languages used for making these models may include UML and BPMN.

For making some business-level enterprise architectural diagrams with ArchiMate, you could model

1. the stakeholders and their concerns in a *Stakeholder View* diagram;
2. the organization structure as nested block diagrams, but also in a more traditional way, such as organizational charts;
3. the business functions of your enterprise in a *Business Function View* diagram.