# Diagrams for Overview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, uml

I have three projects in a Visual Studio solution. The first project is a Windows Forms project which is the UI for the application. The second project is a C++ dll project which is used for interoperability between the first and third projects. The last project is C source code which is imported as C++ source code and compiled as a static library. Project 1(WinForms) depends on Project 2(C++) which depends on Project 3(C).

The Application is basically used to test the C code by giving it inputs and analysing the output in the UI.

I have been given the source code and asked to make an structural overview of the source code using diagrams.

How do I draw diagram showing the workflow of the entire application?

Comment: "Overview of the source code" is too vague.  Do you want to diagram its structure or its behavior?  The answer to your question so far is that you should start with any of about 5 diagrams, depending on the perspective of the overview.  To clarify this, if someone says give me an overview of the office using diagrams, they could want a map of the cubicle layout, an org chart of the people there, the computer network infrastructure, or even the electrical wiring.  So, we need more information before we can give any sort of reliable advice.

Comment: I need to show what are the classes and interfaces, which class is instanciated where and the flow between these. I know we can use class diagrams, object diagrams, sequence diagrams etc. But how is this done in one single diagram? Is there a way to do it without UML?

Comment: For some discussion about the one-for-all diagram without UML see [Stack Overflow: What information is described by an Enterprise Architecture Diagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586352/what-information-is-described-by-an-enterprise-architecture-diagram)

Comment: In UML there's no diagram style designed to be both `Structure Diagram` and `Behavior Diagram` and super compact. Check examples in http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html (including the `Interaction Overview`) and you'll get an idea of what's possible UML-wise

Comment: A structural overview and a workflow are two different things.  That's why you need (at least) two different diagrams to show them.  Perhaps an analogy will help.  Suppose I have a factory that makes widgets.  The layout of the floor, where all the machines are, what type they are is one thing.  How the widgets move through that system is another.  But when you say "flow between these" you may be asking about how the classes are connected.  If so, class diagram will handle all of it.  Otherwise, use a class diagram for the interfaces and classes, and probably an activity diagram for the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your raw needs, you have the [deployment diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram).

The [Unified Modeling Language User Guide](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/799556306) says (chapter 31):

> You use deployment diagrams to model the static deployment view of a system. For the most part, this involves modeling the topology of the hardware on which your system executes. Deployment diagrams are essentially class diagrams that focus on a system's nodes.

However, I see in your comments that you indent to represent classes on your diagram. The deployment diagram will not allow to do so. The deployment diagram is, just like the class diagram, an architectural diagram. The [Unified Modeling Language, Superstructure, V2.1.2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1.2/Superstructure/PDF/) states that (p. 202):

> Deployment diagrams show "the allocation of [Artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)) to Nodes according to the Deployments defined between them." .

This is probably because an artifact is a classifier that the guide says deployment diagrams are class diagrams: representing complete classes on a deployment diagram would be a nonsense (and no modeling tool will probably allow you to do so).

Comment: Essentially class diagrams--yes, but they serve different purposes as you have mentioned.